# wso2 emm 2.2.0 pushing apk to android

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I am using wso 2.2.0 with emm agent installed on a hugerock tablet. The agent is customized such that user does not see gui.. and login  uses imei and imsi of the tablet.    There are around 5000 + similar devices and the problem is emm agent always disconnect and user have to reenroll to make it to work.The reenrol proves tedious and it may not always work.  Pushing apk is not straighforward and we have less than 20% sucess rate.
- is there any way to make the agent reenrol itself or retry on its own
- how to improve the sucess  rate.?

advice is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

WSO2's EMM and IoT Platform is now being developed and supported by Entgra (https://entgra.io).
See https://wso2.com/library/iot/

Entgra is WSO2's Technology partner for EMM and IoT. Team behind Entgra are the same WSO2 team that developed WSO2 IoT and EMM Platform.

The easiest solution to the problem you have described is migrating to a newer version of the product where this problem is fixed. WSO2 EMM 2.2.0 is almost 2.5 years old and there have been many improvements that has gone to product ever since. We are migrating all customers on EMM 2.2.x to 3.x.x.

Entgra released IoT Server 3.5.0 yesterday (https://entgra.io/emm) with a specialised focus on Kiosk Management.

If your interested in discussing how we can help you further, please drop a note to ***contact(AT)entgra.io*** on how we can reach you.

Thanks,
Sumedha